# Invalid block tag on line 90: 'cart_product_form', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I keep getting this error when I add the 2 lines below in the cart app in  `cart/detail.html`

```
{% item.update_quantity_form.quantity show_label=False %}
{% item.update_quantity_form.update %}
```

and a line below in the product app in `products/product_detail.html`

`{% cart_product_form %}`

how can I solve this error?
Invalid block tag on line 90: 'cart_product_form', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

---

**eshop_cart/views.py**

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                 quantity=cd['quantity'],
                 update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('cart_detail')


def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(
            initial={
                'quantity': item['quantity'],
                'update': True
            })
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

---

**eshop_products/views.py**

```
def product_detail(request, *args, **kwargs):
    selected_product_id = kwargs['productId']
    product = Product.objects.get_by_id(selected_product_id)
    if product is None or not product.available:
        raise ("not valid")

    related_product_pictures = ProductGallery.objects.filter(product_id=selected_product_id)
    pictures = MainTopSlider.objects.all()
    cart_product_form= CartAddProductForm()

    context = {
        'product': product,
        'related_product_pictures': related_product_pictures,
        "pictures": pictures,
        'cart_product_form': cart_product_form

    }
    return render(request, 'products/product_detail.html', context)
```

**eshop_products/templates/products/product_detail.html**

```
 <div class="pro-details-cart">
<form action="{% url "cart_add" product.id %}" method="post">
{% cart_product_form %}
{% buttons %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-product">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart
</button>
 {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

**eshop_cart/templates/cart/detail.html**

```
 
 

{% for item in cart %}
{% with product=item.product %}
 <tr>
 <td class="product-thumbnail">
<a href="#"><img class="img-responsive ml-3" src="{% if product.image %}{{product.image.url }}{% else %} {% static "assets/images/no_image.png" %} {%endif %}" alt="" /></a>
</td>
<td class="product-name"><a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{product.name}}</a></td>
                                <td class="product-price-cart"><span class="amount">{{ item.price }}</span></td>
                                <td class="product-quantity">

                                 <form action="{% url 'cart_add' product.id %}" method="post">
                                 {% csrf_token %}
                                {% item.update_quantity_form.quantity show_label=False %}
                                {% item.update_quantity_form.update %}
                                {% buttons %}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-product">
                                        Update
                                    </button>
                                {% endbuttons %}
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-product">
                                                Update
                                            </button>

                                </form>
                                    <div class="cart-plus-minus">
                                        <input class="cart-plus-minus-box" type="text" name="qtybutton" value="1" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="product-subtotal">{{ item.total_price }}</td>
                                <td class="product-remove">
                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-close"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endwith %}
                        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is `{% cart_product_form %}`. Is it the custom template tag? So us what is `{% cart_product_form %}`?

Comment: I edited my question and {% cart_product_form %} is related to the form I created in forms.py

Comment: @ma_as `{% <some_tag> parameters %}` is the syntax for using a **template tag** did you mean to write `{{ cart_product_form }}`? (`{{ <some_variable> }}` is the syntax for rendering a variable)

Comment: @ma_as And this `{% item.update_quantity_form.quantity show_label=False %}` what is this supposed to do? This can neither be a template tag nor a variable. Are you trying to  call some function here? This sort of calling functions with parameters is not possible in Django templates unless you implement a custom template tag.

Comment: thank you for your help I got it, these were variable and I copied like this  {% bootstrap_field item.update_quantity_form.quantity show_label=False %} and just removed the bootstrap_field and similar thing like that and I forgot to remove %.

Comment: is this {% bootstrap_form cart_product_form %} a tag or variable? is there any documentation to help to don't these mistakes again?

Comment: is this a bad question? should I delete it?

Comment: by the way, it worked after removing % and adding {}

Comment: @ma_as In `{% bootstrap_form cart_product_form %}` here `bootstrap_form` is a template tag which you would have loaded somewhere at the start of your template (`{% load bootstrap4 %}` perhaps). It is not that bad of a question you can take a try at answering it yourself now that you see the issue. :)  Also remember to `@` people when you reply to them so that they will get a notification.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat  yeah thank you so much